# Display Outlook Appointment Extended Properties in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to display outlook appointment extended properties in a custom outlook form or maybe an outlook addin? I have set the extended properties against the appointments using EWS. An example of how I have set them is below:

```
private static readonly ExtendedPropertyDefinition extendedPropertyEventID = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(
                                                                                    new Guid("{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"),
                                                                                    "EventID",
                                                                                    MapiPropertyType.String);


appointment.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyEventID, "123456");
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it if you are writing an outlook addin and If you are using the Outlook Object Model, all custom properties are available in the item's UserProperties collection (e.g. AppointmentItem.UserProperties).

Best Practices for Getting and Setting Properties
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869735(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869735%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this just in Outlook you can modify the current view. Here is the procedure for an English Outlook 2007:

1. Go to *View*/*Current View*/*All appointments*:

[image: View_Current View_All appointments]

2. Right click on a column header, choose *Customize current view*, then *Fields*, then in the top left drop down *User-defined field in folder*:

[image: New User-Defined Field]

3. Add the names and types of your User-defined field. [Make sure to pick Integer not Number for Integer fields](https://superuser.com/questions/699715/outlook-not-displaying-integer-user-defined-field-in-calendar-other-types-ok).

---

Edited to add: Note that in that drop down from point 2 you can also choose a form. Maybe that helps you if you want to do it through a form. I have no experience with this.